# Bootstrap Sidebar footer bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this sidebar code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper" style="background-color:#FFFFFF; border: 2px solid #8AC007;">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="#" id="sideHeader" style="background-color: #B4DDF1;">
                        MeetingBook
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="mb-sidebar-username" style="width: 80%;"> <h6>Buongiorno {{displayName}}</h6></div>
                    <a href="#creaMeeting">
                        I Tuoi Meeting
                    </a>
                    <!-- <div class="customHr">.</div> -->
                    <a href="#repositories">
                        Archivio
                    </a>
                </li>


                <li id="footer">
                    <!-- <footer class="block" style="display: table-row; height: 1px;"> -->
                        <div class="customHr">.</div>
                        <div style="width: 100%;">
                            <a href="#repositories" >
                                Copyright e note legali
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="customHr">.</div>
                        <a href="#repositories">
                            Versione
                        </a>
                        <div class="customHr">.</div>
                        <a href="#repositories">
                            Invio log e feedback
                        </a>
                         <div class="customHr">.</div>
                         <a href="#repositories">
                            Preferenze
                        </a>
                        <div class="customHr">.</div>
                        <a href="<c:url value="/security/logout" />">
                            Esci
                        </a>
                        <div class="mb-sidebar-footer-logo" style="background-color: #B4DDF1;">
                            <img src="<c:url value="/img/distro_sidebar_footer_logo.png" />" class="img-responsive"/>
                        </div>
                    <!-- </footer> -->
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't able to position id = footer bottom. If I use position: fixed; bottom:0; the footer goes down, but when close sidebar footer element remain on the main page.
Some advice?

Thanks.

Comment: so, then move out from `sidebar-wrapper`

Comment: I can't it must be into sidebar-wrapper .